# ruby read a file and select best results

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying to pick the best 3 results from a CSV file. Reading the file is no problem, but I can't pick the best results from my file.

This is what I have so far to pick the best 3 results from a file :

**CSV file:**

```
Brain 345677
Mary 5
John 23355676
William 432200
Jessica 21
```

**Ruby code:**

```
elements = []

file = File.open'ballots.csv', 'r' do |file|
  header = false

  ballots = []
  results = []

  while line = file.gets
    unless header
      element = line.split ','

      if [:ballots1] > [:ballots2]
        results = ballots1
      end
    else
      results = ballots2
    end

    puts "#{element[3]}:#{element[4]}"
  end

  header = false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this example help:

```
x = <<HERE
Mary,5
John,23355676
William,432200
Jessica,21
HERE

x.split("\n").sort{|a,b| a.split(',')[1].to_i <=> b.split(',')[1].to_i}[0..2]

# => ["Mary 5", "Jessica 21", "William 432200"]
```

If you want to reverse the sort then change it to this:

```
x.split("\n").sort{|a,b| b.split(',')[1].to_i <=> a.split(',')[1].to_i}[0..2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and welcome to Ruby. Your code looks very complicated and actually doesn't seem to work.

Using Ruby's [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class, I'd do something like this:

```
require 'csv'

elements = {}

CSV.foreach("ballots.csv", col_sep: " ", converters: [:integer]) do |row|
  elements[row[0]] = row[1]
end

elements
#=> {"Brain"=>345677, "Mary"=>5, "John"=>23355676, "William"=>432200, "Jessica"=>21}

sorted = elements.sort_by { |name, ballots| ballots }.reverse
#=> [["John", 23355676], ["William", 432200], ["Brain", 345677], ["Jessica", 21], ["Mary", 5]]

top_3 = sorted.first(3)
#=> [["John", 23355676], ["William", 432200], ["Brain", 345677]]
```

- `elements = {}` creates an empty hash, our data structure for storing the CSV data
- `CSV.foreach("ballots.csv", col_sep: " ", converters: [:integer])` reads `ballots.csv` and executes the block (`do ... end`) for each row, using space (`" "`) as the column separator (`col_sep`) and automatically converting integers (`converters: [:integer]`)
- inside the block, `row` can be accessed like an array, i.e. `row[0]` is the first field, `row[1]` the second and so on
- `elements[row[0]] = row[1]` creates a new key-value pair with `row[0]` (the name) as the key and `row[1]` (the number of ballots) as the value
- `elements.sort_by { |name, ballots| ballots }` sorts the collection ascending by ballots (converting it to an array, but that doesn't matter), `.reverse` reverses it (making it descending)
- `sorted.first(3)` finally returns the top 3 entries

Comment: There should be 3 best, not just max one

Comment: +1 for `require 'csv'`.  Good code is often lazy code, preferring to let someone else do the work.

Comment: Hi Stefan thanks a lot for your help.... I have try but it does not do anything :( any reasons why?

Comment: The program has no output, maybe you have to add `puts top_3`